# ModuleNotFoundError, when I try to import models into another custom folder

Tags: python, django

Inside the **app** I created a scrapers folder and there are two files in it: `__init__.py` and `asana.py`. In asana.py I am trying to import models when and I try to run the `asana.py` imported models giving the following error `ModuleNotFoundError`,

### UPDATED

In the end I didn't understand why I can't run `python asana.py` and get an error ModuleNotFound. But I tried a different approach. imported `Asana` class into tests.py.

**tests.py**

```
from projects.scrapers.asana import Asana

URL = "https://app.asana.com/aprojecturl"
projects = Asana(URL, "23123123", "keyw")
projects.setProjectsIntoDatabase()
```

So called and run the class in tests.py then it worked? There is no module not found error... But still not understand why I can't do the `python asana.py` and get the module not found error?

Django structure

```
--- projects
    --- models.py 
    --- scrapers
        ---__init__.py
           asana.py
```

**asana.py**

```
from projects.models import Project

class Asana:
  def __init__(self, url, team, keyword=None):
    self.url = url
    self.projectKeyWord = keyword
    self.team = team
    self.rawData = []
    self.projects = []

  def setAsanaData(self):
    res = requests.get(self.url, headers={"Authorization": "Bearer 0/"}).json()
    self.rawData = res["data"]

  def setProjects(self):
    if self.projectKeyWord:
      for project in self.rawData:
        if project["name"].startswith(self.projectKeyWord):
          project["team"] = self.team
          self.projects.append(project)

  def getProjects(self):
    self.setAsanaData()
    self.setProjects()
    return self.projects

  def setProjectsIntoDatabase(self):
    self.getProjects()
    for project in self.projects:
      defaults = {"name": project["name"]}
      Project.objects.update_or_create(pid=project["gid"], defaults=defaults)


URL = "https://app.asana.com/aprojecturl"
projects = Asana(URL, "23123123", "keyw")
projects.setProjectsIntoDatabase()
```

why can't I import the models?

Comment: Is there an __init__.py inside `/projects`?

Comment: try `from ..models import Project`

Comment: yes there is. @Danoram

Comment: sorry not to mentioning it, already tried but not working. @RedCricket

Comment: are you working in pycharm??

Comment: yes I am. @BhavyaParikh

Comment: then try to make root directory to projects folder or add python path